# Article re-submission - PI is not responding to requests

Tags: publications, authorship

I, a PhD student, was first author of an article with several co-authors under a PI.  We submitted the article to a journal and it was rejected.  Is there a common practice for resubmitting work? Can I just expect to be first author of a resubmission, or can the PI remove me or designate someone else? I asked the co-authors to meet to talk about revising and resubmitting the work. In response, the PI asked me to communicate with him/her only. S/he is not responding to my requests to meet to talk about getting the paper ready for resubmission. I can't tell how long I should wait for him/her to respond. I'm also not sure if I should continue with re-writing/analysis if there's no agreement about what exactly we're doing. What's a cordial and professional way to handle this?

Comment: Time scale is important here - approximately how long between emails, how many of them, how much time has elapsed since the person has not responded? Being annoyed about a rejection is common, people often need a little time to recover from the sting of harsh reviews before diving back in. But its very different situation if they haven't replied within a few days/week, vs not replying after multiple emails spread out across weeks+, etc. Good to also know if they are reachable by alternative communication means - in person appointment, phone/text, Slack, etc. Email is universal and oft ignored.

Comment: How long would you say one should wait before following up?/How persistent would you say is reasonable?

Comment: Personally, I'd say it is based on my prior experience with that person more than anything, but in general if things are not urgent I don't expect an urgent response (no impending deadline of doom). If I don't get a response in a week, I don't even think anything of it. Post-rejection, I expect 1-4 weeks before anyone even wants to talk about it - the more involved before, the less they want to talk right away, especially if the next deadline is 6+ months away. Friendly check-in after a week is fine, another the next week. No response still, little concern, try alternate method, etc.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. You are studying to become an independent researcher, you have a paper together with some other folks, and your PI forbids you from contacting them? Maybe I just misunderstood, but to me this sounds like a bigger issue than the PI not answering your mails.